# Where do I connect the two red SATA cables on my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, sata

I have a Compaq Presario PC SR5110NX. The Processor is AMD Athlon 64 3800+. It has 512 MB of RAM and a 40GB Hard Drive. I'm running Windows XP Professional on it.

I have 2 SATA drives, one is black and the other is white. I have 2 red little cables, and they have the letters and numbers on them. On one side of the cable it says "HP P/N:5188-2897 0720".

My motherboard is a MCP61PM-HM Rev 1.0B. Where do I connect the two SATA connectors?

Comment: You need to be more specific and detailed in what you are doing or trying to accomplish.

Comment: See the upgrading and servicing guide...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/manualCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=3436819&task=&

Answer (score 1):

According to the HP website, this is the motherboard contained in your computer.
[image: MCP61PM-HM]

Note in the rectangle, this board in some configurations can have 4 SATA ports, but your system only has two, one Black (data1) and one White (data2).

If this is like most assembly line friendly computer systems produced now, one red cable goes from the black drive to the black SATA port, the other red cable goes from the white drive to the white SATA port.

Comment: though, i would note most drives i've seen have black connectors, and it shouldn't matter *which* port you plug it into. from the size of the drive, i'm also assuming the current drive is using a legacy PATA port

Comment: True. I've been working on these things since MFM servo driven head 10MB Winchester drives. It's such a breath of fresh air to work on the newer stuff as you just plug it together and it pretty much sets itself up. At it's inception, Plug N' Play didn't, now you can't imagine life without it. Just go into BIOS and set the boot order. The color coding was from some newer systems I had to work on, since he's got HP cables I'm guessing the drives are OEM, of course if you're not working with OEM, the peripheral connectors will all be black.

Comment: eh, i just wish they would hurry up and globally replace pins with those awesome slot style connectors.

Comment: (Remembering using fine needle nose pliers to straighten bent over pins in HD-15 VGA connector on new $800 monitor) Hear you on that one!